# OpenApi context in API Platform (usecase: anyOf)

Tags: api-platform.com

Oke i'm a bit lost on the use of anyOf as referenced in [the OpenAPiI V3 docs](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md) in the api platform.

Now, per [api platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#using-the-openapi-and-swagger-contexts) docs we can pass on openapi context as follows

```
 * @ApiProperty(
 *     attributes={
 *         "openapi_context"={
 *             "type"="string",
 *             "enum"={"one", "two"},
 *             "example"="one"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
```

Unfortunalty I cant find docs (or examples) on te use of anyOf. Now following the previeus example I would expect it to be something along the lines of

```
* @ApiProperty(
 *     attributes={
 *         "openapi_context"={
 *             "anyOf"={
 *                  "type"="string",
 *                  "type"="url",
 *                  "type"="base64"
 *             },
 *             "example"="one"
 *         }
 *     }
 * )
```

That unfortunatly doesn't work.

Additionally it's unclear how to give an example, description etc per anyOf.

Answer (score 0):

If it's of any use for someone who comes here, the following PHP 8 attribute works :

```php
#[ApiProperty(openapiContext: [
    'anyOf' => [
        ['type' => 'string'],
        ['type' => 'url'],
        ['type' => 'base64'],
    ]
])]
```